# What is an "Irensavelite"

Tags: campaign-settings, glorantha

From an old WorldofGlorantha@yahoogroups.com message:

> > 1.Did 2nd Age God Learners acknowledge Hrestol as their prophet?
> >     (There is no mention in Abiding Book about Hrestol and Joy.)
> >     MRQ setting said YES. But I said Greg's current idea MIGHT NOT BE.
>
> As far as I know, they did - or at least didn't regard him as a raving
>   heretic. The Irensavelites they certainly didn't like, but not all
>   Hrestoli are Irensavelite.

and from [a later message](http://games.groups.yahoo.com/group/WorldofGlorantha/message/6239):

> > Should I interpret above as 3rd Age Irensavalites don't revere
> >     Hrestol, either?
> >     I expected most of 3rd Age Loskalmi are New Hrestoli and
> >     Irensavalite.....their prophets are Malkion and Hrestol.
> >     Please tolerate my limited English ability.
>
> The Loskalmi and the Immaculates are both Irensavelite and Hrestoli.
>   The Castle Coasters are Hrestoli, but not Irensavelite. So the MSE can
>   dislike the Irensavelites (the ancestors of the modern Loskalmi)
>   without disliking all Hrestoli (many of whom are the ancestors of the
>   modern Castle Coasters).
>
> Hrestol himself was not an Irensavelite; that came later, notably from
>   Tomaris. When LotW2 is eventually released, with its list of heresies
>   against the Rokari Church, you'll see that the Hrestoli Heresy and the
>   Fronelan Heresy (i.e. Irensavelism) are not the same thing - although
>   the Loskalmi practice both, of course.

I can't find mention of these Irensevalite's anywhere!  It is apparently a doctrine of an offsplit of the Syanoran church (to judge from the link to the "Fronelan heresy"; cf. the heresies section at the end of [Trotsky's The Syanoran Church write-up](http://www.ttrotsky.pwp.blueyonder.co.uk/malkioni/Jonatela-2a.htm)).  So, who were they?

Comment: I thought it was about time we had a nice, technical Glorantha question...

Comment: I know nothing about Glorantha, so won't post this as an answer, but [this page](http://glorantha.wikia.com/wiki/Irensaval) implies that Irensevalites are worshipers of Irensaval, the Invisible God of the Idealist Church. Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: @dpatchery: Bingo!  Thanks to your link, I've tracked down the source, via [a Moon Design forum post](http://forum.rpg.net/showthread.php?515281-Glorantha-Kingdom-of-War&p=12182361#post12182361) to [Revealed Mythologies #7](http://index.rpg.net/display-entry.phtml?mainid=5264).  Do post that as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This page](http://glorantha.wikia.com/wiki/Irensaval) implies that Irensevalites are worshipers of Irensaval, the Invisible God of the Idealist Church.

Comment: ...and with the help of keywords inferered from this page, we can track down the source, discover the original Irensevalites were adverseries of the God Learners in the 2nd age, &c.  Possibly someone turns up with cool pointers information on these folk, but my question is basically answered.

Comment: @Alticamelus I figured this wouldn't *completely* answer your question, but I'm glad it helped you get there :)